# flyway - tell flyway to repair the migration table BUT keep the history of failed deployments

Tags: flyway

I'd like to be able to deploy to my database after a deployment failure, because in my case I am dealing with concurrent and independent deployments.
the flyway clean command helps to remove failed migrations in the migration table. Using that command helps as my future deployments will be executed but the downside is that I lose the history of failed deployments.

Is there a way to tell flyway to repair the migration table and keep the history of failed deployments - say put the success flag to '2' for example.

In my case all deployments are independents so we create unique migration numbers at deployment time - this allows us to redeploy anything without consideration of flyway's status (we re only using the automation mechanism provided with flyway and have disabled other 'migration' safeguards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported natively. I agree that removing the history of failed migrations would be handy to have as an option.

Use of the [callbacks](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks) may give you a workaround. Specifically you could take a copy of failed migrations in the beforeRepair callback. If using SQL files make a beforeRepair.sql (or whatever you have for your migration suffix).

Comment: Well spotted. IMO this is an acceptable workaround until there is a native support for it.